# How do I retrieve matches for every possible pair of numbers in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I need to find a regular expression that retrieves every possible pair of numbers that are together in a string.

I have tried with `/\d{2}/g` and `/[0-9][0-9]/g` and it burns the char after it matches it once.

input: `"1234567890"`

output with the regexp up there: `["12", "34", "56", "78", "90"]`

required output: `["12", "23", "34", "45", "56", "67", "78", "89", "90"]`

Comment: regex doesn't seem like the right tool for the job.

Comment: You could use overlapping matches like `(\d)(?=(\d))` and then get group 1 and 2 or `(?=(\d\d))` and then get only group 1. See https://rextester.com/RTWT22863 and https://rextester.com/IQQP46046

Comment: Hope there would be a way with regex, I would use loops and individual test if I could

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
const re = /\d{2}/g
let str = "1234567890"
let arr = str.match(re)
str = str.slice(1)
arr = arr.concat(str.match(re))
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a - b))
```

Comment: like that, but only with regex

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to return a character and not consuming it using `match`. However, you could chain a `replace` and a `match` to achieve the expected result.

```
let input = '1234567890';
let output = input.replace(/\d(?=\d)/g, (m, i) => m + input[i + 1]).match(/\d\d/g);
// ["12", "23", "34", "45", "56", "67", "78", "89", "90"]
```